# Change role of RETIRED user in Skype group chat

Tags: skype, chat, administration

In existing Skype group chat, i cannot add one specific user.

When i enter `/showmembers` , it gives:

> andrew USER
>
> bobby ADMIN
>
> catrin USER
>
> diana RETIRED

in this case: i'm *bobby* the admin and *diana* is our user in question. So:

- i cannot add her to chat - i get: `diana can't be added until they accept your contact request.`, and she gets: `You have been removed from this conversation and will not be able to join.`
- i cannot `/set role USER` - `diana can't be added until they accept your contact request.`
- i cannot remove her with `/kick` - nothing happens
- i cannot ban this user with `/kickban` - i see the list of commands, so probably this is deprecated
- giving the link to join chat also does not work, even with options `JOINING_ENABLED`

version of skype is 6.21.0.104 Windows 7.

*Reading on the internet, i suspect that Skype/Microsoft might have broken the group chats. Yet i hope this is not the case, and my problem can be solved.*

Question: **How to add a user who is RETIRED to the group chat ?** or change his role to USER ?

Comment: looks similar to unanswered http://superuser.com/q/818003/102191